# nginx, only allow certain IPs to access a URL prefix

Tags: nginx, access-control-list

In nginx, how can I restrict access to a certain URL prefix by IP address. i.e. “only these IPs are allowed to access `$URL`?”.

I have a `location … {` directive, but it looks like the [nginx `allow` & `deny`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) do no work inside `locations`

I want all IP addresses to be able to access all parts of the server, but I want only a set few IP addresses to be able to access this URL prefix

nginx v 1.18.0 installed via apt on Uuntu Linux 22.04

Comment: Of course they do work in `location`s. *Context: http, server, **location**, limit_except*.

Comment: Please share your full configuration as shown by `nginx -T` and clear details about "allow & deny do not work inside locations".

Answer (score 3):

To restrict access to a specific URL prefix in Nginx based on IP addresses, you can use the `allow` and `deny` directives inside a `location` block. The `allow` directive specifies which IPs are allowed, and the `deny` directive blocks all others. Here's how you can configure it:

- Define a `location` block that matches your URL prefix.
- Inside this block, use `allow` for each IP address you want to grant access.
- Use `deny all` to block all other IP addresses.

Here's an example config for Nginx:

```
server {
    # ... other server config ...

    location /your_url_prefix/ {
        allow 192.168.1.100;   # Allow this IP
        allow 192.168.1.101;   # Allow another IP
        deny all;              # Deny all other IPs

        # ... other location config ...
    }
}
```

In this example, replace `/your_url_prefix/` with your specific URL prefix and `192.168.1.100`, `192.168.1.101` with the IP addresses you want to allow. After updating the configuration, make sure to reload Nginx to apply the changes.

- Summary: Configure Nginx to restrict access to a specific URL prefix by IP using `allow` and `deny` directives within a `location` block.